# Socket.io only works on reconnect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I'm building a React application that connects to a Nodejs API and I'm trying to implement the Socket.io library. I followed some tutorials in the internet and my code right now looks like this:

API:

```
import express from 'express';
import socketIo from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';

const app = express();
const port = 3300;

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo({ 
    serveClient: false,
    transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ],
    pingTimeout: 3000,
    pingInterval: 3000,
    allowUpgrades: false,
    upgrade: false,
    cookie: false
}).listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("------------------------- CONNECTED!!!");
    app.get('/change_name', (req, res) => {
        console.log("Change Name");
        const { name } = req.query;
        res.sendStatus(200);

        console.log('Emitting Event');
        socket.emit('name', name);
    });
});

server.listen(port, err => err ? throw err : console.log("Server online. Listening to port " + port);
```

And in my React app:

```
import React from "react";
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

export default class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "Thiago"
    };

    console.log("Open Socket");
    const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3300', {
      transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ],
    }); 
    console.log("Set event listener");
    socket.on('name', name => {
      console.log('receiving event')
      this.setState({ name });
    });
  }

  render() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Now, the thing is I can only make this work if the web app reconnects with the websocket. To illustrate:

With my App and API running, I hit localhost:8888 in my browser to access the app. The API sucessfully logs `------ CONNECTED` and I can't see any errors in my browser network tab, so I'm guessing the connection worked fine. But then, when I hit the `/change_name` route, nothing happens. The API logs both `Change Name` and `Emmitting Event`, but the browser seems to never receive it (`receiving event` is not logged).

Now, If I to go my terminal e restart my API (withouy refreshing the browser), first I get an error in the browser saying my ws connection was lost. As soon as the API starts running again, I can see the `-------- CONNECTED` log, meaning the browser has successfully reconnected with the server and if I hit `change_name` again, now everything works fine! If I refresh the browser the everything stops works again and I need to restart my API again.

I have tested this both in local and in a remote server (AWS) and the behavior is the same. Nothing happens in the first connection, after restarting the API and the browser automatically reconnects, it all works fine.

Does anyone know what could be causing this behavior? Maybe I'm missing something in the configuration?

Thanks!

Comment: https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34

Idk if this article will help any but might be useful, good luck

Comment: Steve, this was exactly the tutorial I had followed, but idk why I had removed the subscription part =S (though I made it work without it the first time). Adding the subscription part indeed solve my problem. I'll elaborate in the answer.

Comment: im glad it solved it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As Steve pointed in the comments, [this](https://medium.com/dailyjs/combining-react-with-socket-io-for-real-time-goodness-d26168429a34) tutorial explains how to correctly implement socket.io.

It looks like I was missing the subscription part. When I added it, things started working. The code is now like this:

API:

```
import express from 'express';
import socketIo from 'socket.io';
import http from 'http';

const app = express();
const port = 3300;

const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIo({ 
    serveClient: false,
    transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ],
    pingTimeout: 3000,
    pingInterval: 3000,
    allowUpgrades: false,
    upgrade: false,
    cookie: false
}).listen(server);

io.on('connection', function(socket){
    console.log("------------------------- CONNECTED!!!");
    socket.on('subscribeToName', () => { // <---- add this
        app.get('/change_name', (req, res) => {
            console.log("Change Name");
            const { name } = req.query;
            res.sendStatus(200);

            console.log('Emitting Event');
            socket.emit('name', name);
        }); 
    });
});

server.listen(port, err => err ? throw err : console.log("Server online. Listening to port " + port);
```

And in my React app:

```
import React from "react";
import openSocket from 'socket.io-client';

export default class Header extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      name: "Thiago"
    };

    console.log("Open Socket");
    const socket = openSocket('http://localhost:3300', {
      transports: [ 'websocket', 'polling' ],
    }); 
    console.log("Set event listener");
    socket.on('name', name => {
      console.log('receiving event')
      this.setState({ name });
    });
    console.log("Subscribe to Listener");
    socket.emit('subscribeToName'); // <---- add this
  }

  render() { /* ... */ }
}
```

But this leads to other questions:

1. Why, without the subscription, the socket worked after the server restarted?
2. Now the problem has inverted. It works fine the first time, but If the server restarts, the browser reconnects but don't re-subscribe. Is there a way to automatically re-subscribe to an event after the browser reconnects?

Thanks!